# Не работает background CSS

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 color: #222222;
}


header {
 background: url(../img/first-bg.jpg) no-repeat center top / cover);
 
 height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Golden</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
 <div class="container">
  
 </div>
 </header>

 <section>
 <div class="container">
  
 <footer>
  <div class="container">
  
 </div>
 </footer>
<body>
</html>
```

Не отображается картинка не могу понять почему скачал готовую работу там всё работает! у меня же всё так же само но картинка не отображается почему?

Comment: А вы думаете, что дабавив сюда код без самой картинки, она он у нас чудесным образом заработает?

Answer (score 2):

Скобка лишняя в задании `background`:

```css
body {
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 color: #222222;
}


header {
 background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/) no-repeat center top / cover;
 
 height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Golden</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
 <div class="container">
  
 </div>
 </header>

 <section>
 <div class="container">
  
 <footer>
  <div class="container">
  
 </div>
 </footer>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cпасибо боже а я потратил около часа что бы решить проблему:D

Comment: @On1x_Pavlovich если ответ помог - то отметьте его.